# Does IE 7 have a boxSizing property on the currentStyle object?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I know it doesn't actually act on it, but when I test IE 9 in IE 7 browser mode in IE 7 standards mode it returns the box-sizing property. I'm not sure if this is because I'm emulating IE 7 or if the real IE 7 has this property to. Ultimately I'm trying to determine if I should be using the border-box box sizing in my calculations.

```
var usingBorderBox = ieVersion > 0.0 && ieVersion < 8.0
    || ((containerComputedStyle.boxSizing === 'border-box') 
        && (contentComputedStyle.boxSizing === 'border-box'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IE 7 does not support this property (it's a [CSS 3 property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)). This is just another reason why I use a virtual machine with IE 7 installed when I need to do browser testing. There's an upsetting amount of legacy behavior that IE 9 doesn't emulate when in IE 7 or 8 mode unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. The "box-sizing" thing is definitely post-IE7.

IE7 (like IE6) uses (basically) "border-box" when in quirks mode, and the W3C "content-box" in standards-compliant mode.  You can't tell it to do one or the other.

*edit* — actually I'm a little fuzzy on IE7 in quirks mode; I *think* I remember that it drops back to "traditional" (that is, "border-box") sizing when in quirks mode, but I'm finding some confusing Google results.